# Signing BinarySecurityToken in SOAPUI

Tags: soap, soapui

I am trying to Use SOAPUI to generate the SOAP request which uses WS-Security configuration.
The request requires me to sign the

```
_ Body
- TimeStamp
- and Binary Security Token
```

I'm able to do the body and timestamp part but if I specify "name" as Binary Security token in part portion of generating Signature it gives me error.
Does any body has ever encountered this issue in SOAP-UI?

Answer (score 3):

in your outgoing ws-security configuration you have to add three elements

- Timestamp
- Signature, in the first signature, you have to choose for "key identifier type" BinarySecuritytoken
- Signature, in the second signature, you have to choose for "key identifier type" Issuer Name and Serial Number.
  Then you have to add the signed parts to sign into parts section.
     Each element to sign, you have to note the oder to sign. In my case was Timestamp, Body and then BinarySecurityToken.
     Fill name space with the above elements (Timestamp, Body...), fill the namespace and you have to choose element into Encode section.

Then you have to apply the outogoing security to your request.

I hope to help you.